# Does anyone have an idea why my text under the "topbar" div not floating right?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
        <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Paz, 06 Eyl 2015 18:22:12 GMT">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <title>Bitss</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .fixedWidth {
                width: 1050px;
                height:60px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #topbar {
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                background-color: #0099FF;
                color:black;
            }
            #logoDiv {
                font-weight:bold;
                color: black;
                float;
                left;
                padding-top: 15px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
                border-right: 1px solid #FFCCCC;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            #homeButtonDiv {
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 0.9em;
                padding-left:130px;
                padding-top:15px;
                padding-right: 30px;
                position:absolute;
            }
            #photoGalleryButtonDiv {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size:0.9em;
                padding-left: 250px;
                padding-top: 15px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            #littleWriting1 {
                font-size: 0.5em;
                padding-top: 30px;
                padding-left: 2px;
                float:right;
                position: absolute;
            }
            #littleWriting2 {
                font-size: 0.5em;
                padding-top: 40px;
                padding-left: 8px;
                float: right;
                position: absolute;
            }
            #aboutUsButtonDiv {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size:0.9em;
                padding-left: 380px;
                position:absolute;
                padding-top:15px;
            }
            #projectsButtonDiv {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size:0.9em;
                padding-left: 480px;
                position:absolute;
                padding-top:15px;
            }
            #contactUsButtonDiv {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size:0.9em;
                padding-left: 600px;
                position:absolute;
                padding-top:15px;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="topbar">
                <div class="fixedWidth">
                    <div id="logoDiv">Bitss.com.tr</div>
                    <div id="homeButtonDiv">Home Page</div>
                    <div id="photoGalleryButtonDiv">References</div>
                    <div id="aboutUsButtonDiv">About Us</div>
                    <div id="projectsButtonDiv">Our Projects</div>
                    <div id="contactUsButtonDiv">Contact Us</div>
                </div>
                <div id="littleWriting1">Bilgi Islem Teknolojileri</div>
                <div id="littleWriting2">Servis Saglayiciniz</div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea why my text under the "topbar" div not floating right? Is it because i have the "fixedwidth" div? If so, can you explain what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered your `#littleWriting1` and `#littleWriting2` div's via CSS basically by **removing** `position:fixed` and then using `clear:both;` so that they appear above/below each other (also decreased `padding-top` for `#littleWriting2`)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Smoggs/t9bxyz5b/)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.fixedWidth {
  width: 1050px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #0099FF;
  color: black;
}
#logoDiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  float;
  left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFCCCC;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
#homeButtonDiv {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 130px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
#photoGalleryButtonDiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}
#littleWriting1 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  float: right;
}
#littleWriting2 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
#aboutUsButtonDiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 380px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#projectsButtonDiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#contactUsButtonDiv {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<title>Bitss</title>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="topbar">
      <div class="fixedWidth">
        <div id="logoDiv">Bitss.com.tr</div>
        <div id="homeButtonDiv">Home Page</div>
        <div id="photoGalleryButtonDiv">References</div>
        <div id="aboutUsButtonDiv">About Us</div>
        <div id="projectsButtonDiv">Our Projects</div>
        <div id="contactUsButtonDiv">Contact Us</div>
      </div>
      <div id="littleWriting1">Bilgi Islem Teknolojileri</div>
      <div id="littleWriting2">Servis Saglayiciniz</div>
    </div>
</body>
```